# How to identify app when it goes in background in Kitkat (4.4)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to detect app when it goes in background. Everything works perfect but in `New Android Version 4.4(Kitkat)` its not working. I am unable to find out what's the issue with `Kitkat`. It always returns `false`.

```
public static boolean inBackground(final Context context) {

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: in which method you are calling this??

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)? You might be experiencing the *"will likely break in the future"* part.

Comment: @Kalyanpvs I am calling in onPause()

Comment: @zapi What would be the replacement for it?

Comment: @droiddev i have also faced the same problem..try to call it in onStop then it will work..

Answer (score 2):

Override Activity.onPause() or Activity.onStop(), depending on which level of background you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. The solution is to call this method on onStop().

To simplify, I extend the Activities where I need to detect when app goes to background to class below.

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        if (isApplicationSentToBackground(this)){

            // handle app going into background here
        }
    }

    private boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {

            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was working on all API except Kitkat, but when I checked the stat in the onStop it works fine. Thank you

Comment: @Tamawy can you explain? Is this answer working or not in KitKat? You said it's not working in KitKat then you send it works fine.