# How to handle navigation when tapping on notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I have implemented push notification for the app. When notification is tapped, How to start the application from splash screen if the app is already killed. I want to start from Splash screen if the app is already killed and start from Inside landing screen if the app is already in the background. How to handle this? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your create notification method:

```
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Play around with the intent flags `[resultIntent.addFlags(/*intent flag here*/)]`, if you want to:

> start from Splash screen if the app is already killed and start from
>   Inside landing screen if the app is already in the background.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pendingIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to specify the action which should be performed once the user select the notification.
Example tutorial [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500432/how-to-identify-app-when-it-goes-in-background-in-kitkat-4-4